# C++ Programming Creative Issue Solving

Tags: c++

I must be an idiot, but I just cannot find a way to solve this issue:

I want to make a program that takes a jumbled set of chars. and find all possible English words. My issue is that for the life of me I can't figure out how to make all possible combinations of words. I'm fine with the dictionary cross-check, but it's the jumbling that I'm having issues with. Could someone help with this?

Comment: are you supposed to partition the chars to potentially create multiple words, or are you just supposed to treat the chars as one word?

Comment: Post the ideas you have come up with so far, even if it is pseudo code. Is this homework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are working in C++, you could use the `next_permutation()` algorithm from the standard template library: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/